# what is the proper way of figuring out if an sql statement returns true or false?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So what I am trying to do is filter my apps that are in a folder through a permissions DB Table to decide weather or not the current user is able to access that app. In the beginning of this file I print the sessions id to make sure its set and it returns my id. but when I reach my if statement it returns a value weather or not my sql statement is true or false. what is the proper way of figuring out weather an sql statement returns true or false?

```
<?php

Print_r($_SESSION[user_id]);
$matches = glob("Apps/*.php");
if (is_array($matches)) {
    foreach ($matches as $filename) {
        $filenamesans = basename($filename, ".php"); // $file is set to "index" 
        include"db.inc.php"; //database connection
        $item = "SELECT * FROM Apps WHERE UserID='$_SESSION[user_id]' AND App ='$filenamesans'";
        $result = mysql_query($item);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            echo "<a class='nav2' href='Apps/$filenamesans/index.php'>$filenamesans</a></br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please don't insert unescaped variables into your MySQL query. Also, you're using an obsolete database API. Switch to MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: To answer your question: what you're currently doing seems fine, but I'd use `if(mysql_errno())
{` instead. And maybe add an additional check to see if the number of returned rows is greater than `X` or similar.

Comment: ok well it must be something else other than my code. I guess I'll start checking my DB

Comment: You will want to know if the query actually returns a result, i.e. number of rows >= 1.

Comment: @Jack how do i check that? sorry but i need code.

Comment: I would recommend you read the manual a little more; and while you're at it, look into switching to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be noted that you are establishing a connection to the database for every iteration of your loop, and also it's generally a bad idea to have a query in a loop as it can almost certainly be improved.

Try this:

```
include("db.inc.php");
$items = mysql_query("SELECT `App` FROM `Apps` WHERE
       `UserID`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."'");
$itemarr = array();
while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($items)) $itemarr[$item['App']] = true;

$files = glob("Apps/*.php");
foreach($files as $file) {
    $basefile = basename($filename,".php");
    if( isset($itemarr[$basefile])) {
        echo "<a class='nav2' .......>...</a>";
    }
}
```

This uses a single query to get the user's apps, then looks them up in the array - a significantly faster operation.

Comment: Still nothing. This will be sitting behind a VPN for personal use. so i haven't exactly focused on security. Its driving me nuts because it seems to me that their is nothing wrong with the code. But then again I've only been actively writing php for a few months. Thanks for at least trying! :)

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($itemarr)` to see if there are indeed any apps there.

Comment: This code modified did work. I really liked the only executing the sql statement once thing.